# Create stacked and grouped bars: one bar is hidden?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a group of 4 bars that I want to plot for each point. I have 5 points, so I need to plot 4-bars for each point. Each bar is stacked with two data.

Here is the code and the result shows only a group of 3-stacked bars. There is one hidden bar. What is the problem and how to show the 4-stacked bars?

Also, I do not know why the bar in yellow is not filled?!

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every axis/.style={
        xlabel={Number},
        ylabel={Rate},
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,ymax=11,
        bar width=6pt,
        xtick={2,4,6,...,10},
        xmin=0,xmax=12,
        x label style={font=\footnotesize},
        y label style={font=\footnotesize}, 
        ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    }]
    \begin{axis}[bar shift=-10pt,hide axis]
    \addplot[black,fill=yellow] coordinates {
        (2, 1.73) (4, 1.73) (6, 1.73) (8, 1.73) (10, 1.73)
    };
    \addplot[black,yellow=yellow,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 7.69) (4, 6.98) (6, 6.61) (8, 6.25) (10, 5.91)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
    \addplot+[black,fill=violet] coordinates {
        (2, 1.13) (4, 1.13) (6, 1.13) (8, 1.14) (10, 1.13)
    };
    \addplot+[black,fill=violet,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 6.24) (4, 5.62) (6, 5.28) (8, 4.96) (10, 4.75)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
    \addplot+[black,fill=magenta] coordinates {
        (2, 1.74) (4, 1.74) (6, 1.74) (8, 1.75) (10, 1.75)
    };
    \addplot+[fill=magenta,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 7.59) (4, 6.83) (6, 6.33) (8, 5.91) (10, 5.6)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[bar shift=10pt]
    \addplot+[black,fill=red] coordinates {
        (2, 1.32) (4, 1.32) (6, 1.31) (8, 1.3) (10, 1.3)
    };
    \addplot+[black,fill=red,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 8.37) (4, 7.44) (6, 6.86) (8, 6.38) (10, 5.86)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Creating a stacked and grouped bar chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407169/creating-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the second and third `axis` environment has the same `bar shift` (=0pt), hence they overlaps.

In the following example, I specify `bar shift` to `-12pt, -4pt, 4pt, 12pt` in turn for those four `axis` environments, and add a `width=10cm` to widen the whole figure.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every axis/.style={
        xlabel={Number},
        ylabel={Rate},
        ybar stacked,
        ymin=0,ymax=11,
        bar width=6pt,
        xtick={2,4,6,...,10},
        xmin=0,xmax=12,
        x label style={font=\footnotesize},
        y label style={font=\footnotesize}, 
        ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        width=10cm
    }]
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, bar shift=-12pt]
    \addplot[black,fill=yellow] coordinates {
        (2, 1.73) (4, 1.73) (6, 1.73) (8, 1.73) (10, 1.73)
    };
    \addplot[black,yellow=yellow,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 7.69) (4, 6.98) (6, 6.61) (8, 6.25) (10, 5.91)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, bar shift=-4pt]
    \addplot+[black,fill=violet] coordinates {
        (2, 1.13) (4, 1.13) (6, 1.13) (8, 1.14) (10, 1.13)
    };
    \addplot+[black,fill=violet,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 6.24) (4, 5.62) (6, 5.28) (8, 4.96) (10, 4.75)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, bar shift=4pt]
    \addplot+[black,fill=magenta] coordinates {
        (2, 1.74) (4, 1.74) (6, 1.74) (8, 1.75) (10, 1.75)
    };
    \addplot+[fill=magenta,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 7.59) (4, 6.83) (6, 6.33) (8, 5.91) (10, 5.6)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[bar shift=12pt]
    \addplot+[black,fill=red] coordinates {
        (2, 1.32) (4, 1.32) (6, 1.31) (8, 1.3) (10, 1.3)
    };
    \addplot+[black,fill=red,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
        (2, 8.37) (4, 7.44) (6, 6.86) (8, 6.38) (10, 5.86)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why the yellow bar is not filled with yellow? Also, can we add legend for each color?

Comment: @zdm First question: because there is a typo in your example. It should be `fill=yellow`, but now it is `yellow=yellow`. Second question: I think it is possible. You can post a new question to ask about that.